# How do I get the layout on my device to render like it does in the Eclipse graphical designer?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, rendering

I realize that the Eclipse graphical layout editor often (usually?) doesn't render things the same way that the physical devices or emulator do. I can usually deal with that. However, I have a situation where I can't figure out why there is such a big difference, and more importantly, I can't figure out how to get what I want for a layout on the target devices.

I am attempting to use some custom ImageButton widgets with custom graphics files as buttons. I simply want the buttons to fill the parent layouts they are in. In the designer, they look the way I think they should. But when I run it on a device, the buttons are way to small. Here is what the design looks like, using a device that is set up to emulate the Droid X that I am testing with.

http://pozzy.com/consulting/LayoutDesignInEclipse.PNG

Here is a screen capture of the screen when running on my Droid X:

http://pozzy.com/consulting/ScoreEntryDroidXScreenCapture.png

I tried to trim the code down, but it still relies on a number of button image files. Here is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    Android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/scoreEntryPlayersAndMainEntry"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/scoreEntryPlayers"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight=".5"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:paddingBottom="4dp"
             android:paddingTop="4dp"
             android:paddingLeft="4dp" >                                             
         </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/scoreEntryMainEntry"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight=".5"
             android:maxWidth="100dp"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:paddingBottom="4dp"
             android:paddingLeft="4dp"
             android:paddingRight="4dp"
             android:paddingTop="4dp" >

             <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/scoreEntryPreviousHoleNumberNextRow"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                   android:background="@drawable/score_entry_background_top"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight=".1"
                 android:gravity="center|top" >

                 <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/previousHoleButton"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                     android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:contentDescription="Previous Hole"
                     android:src="@drawable/score_entry_prev" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/holeNumber"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:paddingTop="20dp"
                     android:text="##"
                     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                     android:textSize="24sp"
                     android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/nextHoleButton"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:contentDescription="Next Hole"
                        android:src="@drawable/score_entry_next" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/scoreEntryCurrentScore"
                   android:background="@drawable/score_entry_background_middle"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_weight=".8" >

                 <FrameLayout
                     android:id="@+id/scoreEntryScoreOverlays"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                     <LinearLayout
                         android:visibility="invisible"
                         android:id="@+id/scoreEntryPlayerScoreLayout"
                         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:orientation="vertical" >

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/currentPlayer"
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_margin="10dp"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:text="Player Name"
                             android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
                             android:textSize="16sp"
                             android:textStyle="italic" />

                         <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/currentScore"
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                             android:text="99"
                             android:gravity="center"
                             android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                             android:textColor="#ff0000"
                             android:textSize="100sp"
                             android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
                     </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/scoreEntryScoreDownUpRow"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="@drawable/score_entry_background_bottom"
                 android:gravity="bottom"
                 android:layout_weight=".1"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >
                 <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/scoreDownButton"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_margin="5dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                     android:src="@drawable/score_entry_minus" />


                 <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/scoreUpButton"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_margin="5dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                     android:src="@drawable/score_entry_plus" />

             </LinearLayout>

         </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>     
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help in figuring out how to get the buttons filling their respective areas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you trying to bring same design as you see in emulator? you dont want it in full screen? want to display it in half screen?

Comment: I'm trying to get the design on the device to look the same as in the desig tool in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same problem and I have had to workaround it by manipulating it everytime to fit both places which is sad. The eclipse graphics visualizer really sucks sometimes. I' ve
tried http://www.droiddraw.org/ since many people say that is pretty good - but somehow there seems to be a gap between what is seen on the visualizer and then on the actual device. I guess the rule of thumb is to follow this http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html to the letter and keep trying . I think Droid Draw works for me better than eclipse, I suppose following the dev link above and using say Droid Draw should ideally work for you.

Comment: I have tried DroidDraw, but I can't get it to load my layout with correct references to the drawables. The "Set drawables directory" doesn't really seem to work.

Comment: What I'm looking for help on is the best way to get the buttons to fill their parent, without having to hard-code height and width values. If I can get it displaying well on the devices, I don't care that the graphical design tool doesn't render exactly the same.